# Comparing difference between 2 node lists and 1 array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2 variables that fetch the values of two different checkbox input series into Nodelists (these are user selected colors) and one array containing the master list of all available colors:

```
Color1elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#question5 input:checked");
Color2elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#question10 input:checked");    
var elements = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black"];
```

The idea is to figure out what colors from the master list have not been selected between Color1elementsList and Color2elementsList and store those into another array: ColorelementsLeft.

My efforts:

```
function checkColors(){
    var Color1ArrayElements = []; // empty Array
    var Color2ArrayElements = []; // empty Array
    var ColorelementsLeft = []; // empty Array

//convert nodelist to array
    for (var i = 0; i < Color1elementsList.length; i++) {
        var self = Color1elementsList[i].value;
        Color1ArrayElements.push(self);
    }

//convert nodelist to array
    for (var i = 0; i < Color2elementsList.length; i++) {
        var self = Color2elementsList[i].value;
        Color2ArrayElements.push(self);
    }

    ColorelementsLeft = elements - Color1ArrayElements - Color2ArrayElements;   
    console.log(ColorelementsLeft);
}
```

Obviously the formula for ColorelementsLeft is incorrect but I'm not sure where to start.

Assuming the user selects red and blue in the first input list and then red and yellow on the second, ColorelementsLeft should contain green and black.

Answer (score 4):

```
const colors1 = [...document.querySelectorAll("#question5 input:checked")];
const colors2 = [...document.querySelectorAll("#question10 input:checked")];    
const elements = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black"];

const colorsYetToBePicked = elements.filter(el => !colors1.concat(colors2).includes(el));
```

So a couple of things are happening here primarily in the `[...]` by using the spread syntax we can quickly convert the Nodelist into an Array.

In the second part, we call the function `filter` and set the filtering to exclude the element if its already in either color list.

Comment: i'm getting color1 and color2 not defined errors, but I get the gist of it.

Comment: Are you sure this code works as intended? You can indeed quickly transform a NodeList into an array with the spread `...` operator. However you're still left with an array of DOM nodes. So I'm not sure whether `[Node, Node, Node].includes("red")` (or any other colour) would ever return `true`.

Comment: it would not. Because the actual Array being compared in your example is an actual Node not a string "red". The concept still holds and what would need to be done is something like `[Node, Node].map(el => el.value)` to get an actual array of colors.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd define a function that returns the value of all checkboxes that match given selector:

```
const values = selector =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
    .map(({value}) => value);
```

Then I'd use a selector that can fetch all checked checkboxes in one go. **For that I assume that all checkboxes that need to be processed share the same naming pattern**.

Given this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="red" checked/> red
<input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="blue" checked/> blue
<input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="red" checked/> red
<input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="yellow" checked/> yellow
```

Then the following selector can fetch all checked checkboxes whose name start with "set": (please notice the use of `^` in the selector:

```css
[name^="set"]:checked
```

Then all that is left to do is to construct a list of all possible colours and keep only the colours that haven't been selected yet.

Full code below:

```js
const values = selector =>
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
    .map(({value}) => value);
    
const notIn = arr => val => !arr.includes(val);
    
const coloursLeft = checkedSelector =>
  ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black'].filter(
    notIn([...values(checkedSelector)]));
    
console.log(
  coloursLeft('[name^="set"]:checked')
);
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>set 1</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="red" checked/> red
  <input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="blue" checked/> blue
  <input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="green"/> green
  <input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="yellow"/> yellow
  <input type="checkbox" name="set1" value="black"/> black
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>set 2</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="red" checked/> red
  <input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="blue"/> blue
  <input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="green"/> green
  <input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="yellow" checked/> yellow
  <input type="checkbox" name="set2" value="black"/> black
</fieldset>
```